# linq to entity sqlFunction.string convert return varchar and not nvarchar

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have to write linq to sql server between two tables,the related fields are in a different types. one is string(nvarchar)  and the other is int.

**here is my linq:**

```
from je in a
join vP in b
on je.BaseRef  equals SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal) vP.DocEntry)
```

**the result of the linq in sql was:**

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Account] AS [Account]
FROM  [dbo].[a] AS [Extent1]
JOIN [dbo].[b] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[BaseRef] = (STR( CAST( [Extent2].[DocEntry] AS float)))) OR (([Extent1].[BaseRef] IS NULL) AND (STR( CAST( [Extent2].[DocEntry] AS float)) IS NULL))
```

that query return null because sql can not compare varchar and nvarchar.
linq to entity translate `sqlfunction.stringFormat` to `str('')` and not to `convert(nvarchar,'')`.
how can I convert to nvarchar?

Answer (score 4):

There is a work-around:

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal) vP.DocEntry) + ""
```

This will translate to

```
(STR( CAST( [Extent2].[DocEntry] AS float))) + N''
```

which lifts the whole expression to `nvarchar`.

But I suspect that the comparison between `char` and `nvarchar` should not be a problem. The problem is more likely to be solved by trimming the conversion result:

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal) vP.DocEntry).Trim()
```

Comment: Hello ,Thanks for your reply. I tried it but it returned varchar.

Comment: Are you sure? I checked a similar query with `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY( STR( CAST(  CAST( xxx AS float)) + N'', 'BaseType')`. It was `nvarchar`. But are you sure that a mismatch between `char` and `nvarchar` is the problem? They should compare equally.

Comment: hi gert, I tried it, also with the trim() and it was the same. sql can not compare nvarchar and varchar, sql can compare int and string without converting, but linq to entity does not pass build in this situation.

Comment: Char and nvarchar should compare just fine. Try `SELECT CASE WHEN N'b' = CAST('b' AS char) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` (output: 1). It must be something else. Maybe you should show some sample data (including `BaseRef` and `DocEntry`).

Comment: when i run the query that I got from linq:

Comment: Whan I run the linq above I got no results but when I run the query without converting int to str :"SELECT 
[Extent1].[Account] AS [Account]
FROM  [dbo].[a] AS [Extent1]
JOIN [dbo].[b] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[BaseRef] = [Extent2].[DocEntry]) OR (([Extent1].[BaseRef] IS NULL) AND (STR( CAST( [Extent2].[DocEntry] AS float)) IS NULL))"(sql lets comparing nvarchar and int) I get 2900 results

Comment: This worked great!!! Seems very strange to have to do this but at least it worked.  I use this StringConvert in a join and it worked perfectly, used this in a subselect and it #FailedHard, but .Trim() saved me